# Downvoting: What are the Effects of False Negatives?

Tags: discussion, voting

O.K, so I have at times shown an ugly side of my personality when posting angry comments when being downvoted, and having had the impression that the votes were undeserved.

I understand that it is not good for the health of MSE to have "false positives", i.e., posts that have incorrect answers, and that downvotes are a disincentive to these false positives. Still: how about the problem of false negatives? By this I mean posts that have been downvoted so that they have a net negative score, but these posts have been eventually corrected. Is this something helpful to MSE ? Doesn't this deprive some of the opportunity to learn from posts that are actually correct, believing that there are errors from the net negative score?

I have to admit I am upset too, at the lack of effort to post a comment of the sort of "please check, you got something wrong in last line of 2nd paragraph", and waiting to see if the OP has corrected the mistake(s), and downvoting only if these have not been corrected. Moreover: isn't there an issue of fairness in having downvoters return to the OP to check if the post has been corrected and , if so, removing their downvotes?
This last would not only be fair, but it would help rid MSE of false negatives --if, that is, MSE does not want these false negatives.

EDIT: Could we have a truce? I admit it, I blew up, reacted in a way disproprtionate to the situation. My apologies if I came off too aggressively. Still, just to explain, I received 5 downvotes on old questions in less than 24 hours after I did this meta post. How can one interpret this? O.K, so the tribe has spoken :) , I accept that most people do not agree with me, and I do not want to impose my will. I thought I had a valid point, but it seems more likely I don't.

Comment: Wow, self-reference! Downvoted anonymously on a post on anonymous downvoting. I will call my psychic and ask her why I was downvoted. Shame on me for not being able to read the mind of the downvoter!

Comment: I guess there's someone around who does not like me, so I guess I should expect a few downvotes in my next posts, no matter what I write. BTW , is there a way of telling if one has received downvotes in a given post? Clearly, the identity of the downvoter will remain anonymous, but can one tell if the post was downvoted?

Comment: By clickling on the score of the post. (This requires 1000 rep.)

Comment: Firstly, fear not from downvotes on meta. They mean only that the voter disagrees with you post. Many times people don't read fully the post and just vote against it.

Comment: Secondly, even after correcting an answer some people will not bother to come back to read it and undo their vote. That's just how things are, don't get too excited about it.

Comment: There is no requirement that people explain their downvotes (just as people do not have to explain their upvotes!) and, whilte I think it is nice when they do, it would do wonders for the general ambiance of the site if we did not post angry comments about this (or about anything else, really...) *We are talking about points!!!*

Comment: -1 because the questions in this complaint are only rhetorical. The rhetorical questions are an implied incitement to changing something about voting without saying precisely what, except "don't downvote my posts".

Comment: Phira: I appreciate the fact that at least you bothered explaining. Still, I think I am actually asking some questions, like: don't false negatives also hurt the MSE community, by depriving them of correct answers?

Comment: Gee, 4 downvotes in less than 24 hrs--as many as I had received in all my 8 months here , and all in old questions. I'm sure it's not personal tho, right? Go passive-aggression, go!

Comment: gary, votes on meta do not change the reputation on the main site. As I said on my first comment: this is just a way to express support for/against the discussed idea.

Comment: @Asaf: I am not referring to the ones I received here. I received 5 downvotes on old questions after I did this post.

Comment: If you feel someone has got it in for you the right way to react is to contact the moderators. See the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @gary Please justify your incendiary use of "passive-aggressive", "intimidation", "personal" or apologize for it. Or do you want to pressure people in not downvoting your posts if they think that they are unhelpful? Why should they change their opinion because you attack them? And why are you surprised that people stay anonymous if you attack people who disagree with you?

Comment: @Phira:I was referring to the 5 downvotes I received _after_ I did this post, all done on old posts, not to the previous downvotes. What do you think are the odds that I would receive 5 downvotes in less than 24 hours, all of them on old posts? And, why don't you justify the claim about the "serious errors" you find in the post you referred to? Unhelpful, possibly; serrious errors? I doubt it.Again, to make it clear, I was commenting on the fact that after I did this post in Meta, I received 5 downvotes. Now, what goal do you think underlied these votes?

Comment: @gary The goal is to indicate to other readers that the voters find this post unhelpful. What else? Noone here even knows you. I repeat: Please explain your use of the above-listed words. As to the errors: Since you wrote yourself that you got it exactly wrong you can hardly not know what the serious error is. And *obviously* you get the downvotes now when people look at your posts to get an informed opinion. If someone was after you personally, they would not need a meta thread to go after you.

Comment: @Phira: apparently the downvoters never cared to look at some of my other posts and find a single one they could upvote, hmm....., how likely is that? Re "noone knows you": it is possible to dislike someone's web persona without knowing them personally. In addition, the downvotes were issued _after_ the correction. I'm sorry, I will be gone for a few hours, I am not ignoring.

Comment: gary, you may have a valid point about the 5 downvotes on old questions. To repeat my advice: tell the moderators.

Comment: If you complain about downvoting on your questions in whatever context, people will look them up to see if they were justified. If they consider the answer bad enough, they may downvote themselves.

Comment: I deleted my post on claims I made above, since I have no proof. Still, it is hard for me to believe that these are not a form of retaliation; suddenly all people looking at the--corrected post--agree that it is of poor quality, when , previously, more than 100 did not. And , if you don't like my accusations because you believe they are unfounded, look at my perspective: with 3-+ negative posts, I'm being told I posted garbage, without any argument to back it up, i.e., an unfounded criticism.

Comment: Bloody Hell, gary - if you believe someone is retaliating against you, TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! TELL THE MODERATORS! Time to put up or shut up.

Comment: The whole whining is built on the assumption that the only reason for downvoting is the presence of an error in the post. Another good reason for downvoting though would be to discourage posting false and/or unverified claims. This reason doesn't disappear after you correct your post. For example, I would often leave my downvote, because I don't want to encourage posting false claims and then correcting them. Instead I want to encourage thought out thorough answers. Anyway, everybody decides him/herself what to upvote and what to downvote. If you can't live with that, this site is not for you.

Comment: @Alex B Whining? My claim is that an unexplained downvote represents a loss of information; the answer may be mathematically-correct, but considered unhelpful by a downvoter, but some readers may not be aware of this. These readers would/may appreciate an answer that is correct, even tho not insightful to some. If you cannot bother to read posts carefully, maybe MSE is not for you.

Comment: @Alex B: it would be much more helpful to all who are not experts in the area relating to a post, if there was an explanation not just a downvote.Those knowledgeable in the area know there is something wrong, and are not helped by the downvote; those who are not, have no idea of what--if anything--is wrong with the post (since some downvotes are issued if the post is "unhelpful"). At the end of the day, an unexplained downvote is of little help. The people who  to want to help MSE would help much more with constructive comments. That is all I meant; it may be whining to you, not to me.

Answer (score 15):

I most certainly *will* downvote an incorrect post and I strongly disagree with waiting while an error stands without downvotes.

Downvotes are not for you, they are for other readers. It's not all about you. And it is other people's decision where they spent their time and effort.

Obviously, it is annoying if a correct post is downvoted because the downvoters are mistaken, but you are talking about "corrected" posts, so this is about actual errors where you don't want to be downvoted.

If you don't want to be treated "unfairly", maybe you should just make less errors in your posts.

Personally, I don't feel that the number of votes on my posts corresponds extremely well with the different amount of effort and thought that has gone into each. It has happened that throwaway remarks and easy answers have gathered more enthusiastic votes than well-thought out original contributions.

And the reason for this is that the voters don't reward my inner thoughts and good intentions, they evaluate the post based on what it does for them which depends on all kinds of complicated factors.

On the whole, it works well enough for me to continue to contribute when I find the time and it works well enough for the site to continue to function. If it does not work for you, then it doesn't but you cannot change whether other people find your post helpful or correct by insisting on fairness. What kind of "fairness" should that be? Amount of time you spent on typing the answer?

Comment: "Personally, I don't feel that the number of votes on my posts corresponds extremely well with the different amount of effort and thought that has gone into each. It has happened that throwaway remarks and easy answers have gathered more enthusiastic votes than well-thought out original contributions." - indeed, sadly enough.

Comment: @J.M. absolutely. The general trend is for trivial answers to very elementary questions to get a lot of upvotes, while detailed answers to research-level questions get almost no attention since much fewer people click in. My most-upvoted answer for instance, is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/74348#74348 which required almost no time or thought.

Comment: Phira, do you bother to come and undo the downvote once a correction has been made?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "correction". It is not as if one is notified by an edit of a post one has voted for one way or the other. I don't feel responsible for checking down-voted posts for edits although I certainly undo my downvotes most of the times in practice after an edit. I strongly reject the idea that is implied by the use of "bother". And I have checked the only two posts by the OP that have negative votes and I disagree that they have been "corrected" in a sense that makes them a useful answer.

Comment: @Phira: my definition of fairness here is that once the original reason for downvoting disappears, so should the downvote. Still, what really bothered me is that I had _explicitly_ stated that I was posting something as an answer because I did not have enough points (because of some complications with my account) to post as a comment.

Comment: Phira: in defense of Asaf's use of "bother", as a nonnative English speaker, he may not be aware of the connotation of the word.

Comment: @gary: I am fully aware of the connotation of the word. I do know that many people act as "fire and forget" in voting. This is just me, being cynical.

Comment: @gary: there are [at least two connotations of "bother"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bother#Translations) I'm aware of; it was quite clear to me which one Asaf was using.

Comment: For the record: at the current rate of questions coming in, and my generally being slow, I may forget to undo any downvotes I've cast (and if I ever downvote, I've either already left a negative comment or have upvoted a negative comment previously left), but if the poster has genuinely fixed a previously deficient post, I undo as soon as I see it.

Comment: @Phira:Re: "If you don't want to be treated 'unfairly', maybe you should make less errors in your posts". don't you mean _alleged_ errors? I don't mean this is done neither purposefully nor out of ignorance, but an actual effort to describe the error may help the downvoter as well as others better determine if there really  is such an error, not to mention that both I (and the poster in general) may get some insight.

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry, did not mean to speak for you.

Comment: @user7530 Or perhaps worse than your easy answer getting 17 upvotes is that Didier Piau's mostly useless answer (useless to any one who needed to ask the question) got 58 votes simply because it was one character.

Comment: @Graphth It got 58 votes because it was amusing and it is not misleading. People who don't understand it will hardly spend a long time reading it.

Comment: @gary http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73810/when-is-a-sequence-x-n-subset-0-1-dense-in-0-1/74193#74193
There is nothing alleged or minor in the error in your above answer and your comments below it including "And, by the way, I never downvote without including comments, and I pledge not to do it. To do so seems to be motivated by a desire to punish, more than to enlighten and help." show that this is *exactly* what you are referring to with your complaint here. Downvoting a totally wrong post does in your mind come from a desire to punish.

Comment: @Phira: my point is that until an error is pointed out, it is an alleged error. And notice how , despite three downvotes, not a single comment. Believe me, I do not see what is wrong with that post; I believe the conditions I included were necessary, if not sufficient. And, no, downvoting a post _without an explanation_ seems to be motivated more by a desire to punish than to enligthen. And, BTW, what do you think about the 5 downvotes I received in less than 24 hours after this post? The downvotes were made in old questions?

Comment: @Phira The point is, one of the highest ranking answers of all time on this site is useless to any one who would ask that question.  It is slightly amusing.  But, 5 of the top 10 ranked users of this entire site have never had an answer ranked that high.  And the other 5 of the top 10 have only a combined 6 answers ranked that high.  It got more than 3 times as many votes as an answer that actually was helpful.  And, with the extra attention it got because of this, the ratio may get up to 4 times soon.  And, the answer was edited 3 hours ago to a more block like W.

Comment: @Phira: I believe that the post you refer to, while possibly trite and not helpful, is not incorrect, and has no errors. And yes, I blew up, and I definitely could have handled the downvotes with more class.

Comment: @gary, OK, suppose *you* posted the question, "What are the solutions of $x^2=4$?" and I posted the answer, "Those are the numbers $x$ which, when you calculate $x^2$, give you the number 4." My answer would be not incorrect, and would contain no errors, and if it *didn't* collect a large number of downvotes I'd think something was very wrong with this site. The analogy is imperfect; I'm not equating your actual answer with my hypothetical one; and I would hope that at least one of my downvoters would write some explanation; but.

Comment: @Gerry: you're right. There is the additional fact that (by complicated reasons) did not have enough points to post as a comment. I explicitly stated this, i.e., that I did not have enough votes to post as a comment, which can/should be taken differently from an answer, which is supposed to be more substantial, and, well, an answer. But, yes, I agree otherwise. I was also referring to Phira's statement about my errors not being minor; I believe there is no actual wrong mathematics, however unhelpful the post may have been. I think this distinction matters

Comment: @Graphth I don't think that the W post is problematic. If it were the only answer, I would feel inclined to post another one, sure, but anyone who needs the answer to the question finds a more elaborate answer and then can also think about why the W post gives an answer.
It *is* important to think about this kind of question graphically and not only in formulas. Also, the top ranked posters *are* top ranked posters despite the fact that they did not have fluke posts like this and 60 votes on a post does not necessarily mean 600 reputation.

Comment: @gary I don't get it. You are arguing that since you edited in "This is wrong" under your wrong answer, it is a correct statement now, and cannot have downvotes?

Comment: @gary: I believe the critical word in Phira's last comment is *under*. In fact, I believe that it *can* be beneficial to leave an incorrect answer to prevent others to fool themselves same way you did originally. But *if* you decide to do so, please add a big fat disclaimer **at the beginning** of the post, preferably with some further explanations. This prevents people reading your post from scratching their heads before getting to the line in which you indicate that you goofed. One shouldn't do this on a regular basis, but occasionally I believe there is some pedagogical value in doing this.

Comment: No: what made me upset is that I had explained that I wished to post as a comment, but I did not have enough points to do so, so instead, I was posting as an answer, since it was the only option I had at the moment. Shouldn't that have been taken under consideration?

Answer (score 9):

This is why a downvote only removes 2 reputation, and costs 1 reputation.

I think forcing downvoters to return to posts is a bit much.  Although, I am in favor of giving some sort of notification when the post is edited so that they have the *option* to return.

Comment: So how about the idea of a pingback system that alerts downvoters of an edit?

Comment: @gary, Eric: That is an interesting idea, one of you could propose it on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as a feature to add.

Comment: @Zev: While none of *my* feature requests on this meta has been completed (or even got a response from an SE employee), it is well established that one no longer needs to go to meta.SO for feature requests.

Comment: @Asaf: Ah, I'd forogtten.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any real false negative problem. Answers with negative net score tend to accumulate pity upvotes quickly until they reach 0, unless they are genuinely incorrect or misleading.

A corollary is that having a fresh answer drive-by downvoted will usually cause a net win in reputation.

Comment: Well, then maybe my answer:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73810/when-is-a-sequence-x-n-subset-0-1-dense-in-0-1/74193#74193 with 3 down votes is one of the exceptions. Would someone please explain what is incorrect/misleading about it?

Comment: @gary, Henning is talking about "fresh" answers, not "old" answers to questions that have gone off the front page (especially, I think, if they've been answered with an answer accepted). If no one looks, no one gives "pity" upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to point out that if users really are trying to help out with their downvotes, which I don't exactly believe of many downvotes, then they would explain why they gave one.  A new user who asks a question that does something that is deemed poor form by someone gets a down vote with no explanation.  That may tell people not to look at that one post.  But, it does nothing to teach this user how to make a good post.  So, that user could easily continue to make "bad" posts.  This is worse than making one bad post and learning why it is bad and learning how to make it into a good post.  On the other hand, if someone actually explains why they think the answer deserves a downvote, hopefully the user reads it and thinks about it and becomes a more productive member.  In other words, if downvotes really are for other users, as Phira says, then an explanation would accompany them.

Comment: +1, right: constructive vs. non-constructive criticism. "Your line #2 is ambiguous; the inequality does not hold " vs. "Your post is no good"